# Looking for words from a list of words in a sentence

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, trie

> **Problem**
>
> Given a Dictionary with `user_id` and a list of `alert_words` (words
>   and phrases too look for in an sentence) and a string `content`. We
>   have to look if the `alert_words` appears in the `content` and return
>   the list of `user_ids` who's `alert_words` appears in the `content`
>
> **Example**
>
> input = { 1 : ['how are you'], 2 : ['you are'] }
>
> content = 'hello, how are you'
>
> output = [1]
>
> `user_id` = 1 has 'how are you' while `user_id` = 2 has the words but
>   not in the correct order so only user 1 is returned.

**Solution**

I'm using [Google's pygtrie](https://github.com/google/pygtrie) implementation of `Trie` data structure to achieve this. [[pygtrie documentation](https://pygtrie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)]

Algorithm:

- For each word in the given sentence
- Check if the word is a key, if yes add it to the list of user_ids
- check if the word has a subtrie i.e. that current word is the starting of a alert_word. So add it to another set `alert_phrases`
- for each word in `alert_phrases` we check if we can extent with the current word and do the same set of operations if it is a key/subtrie

**Code**

```
import pygtrie
from typing import Dict, List, Set

def build_trie(realm_alert_words : Dict[int, List[int]]) -> pygtrie.StringTrie:
    trie = pygtrie.StringTrie()
    for user_id, words in realm_alert_words.items():
        for word in words:
            alert_word = trie._separator.join(word.split())        
            if trie.has_key(alert_word):
                user_ids_for_word = trie.get(alert_word)
                user_ids_for_word.update([user_id])
            else:
                trie[alert_word] = set([user_id])
    return trie

def get_user_ids_with_alert_words(trie : pygtrie.StringTrie, content : str) -> Set[int]:
    """Returns the list of user_id's who have alert_words present in content"""
    content_words = content.split()
    alert_phrases = set()
    user_ids_in_messages = set()
    for possible_alert_word in content_words:
        #has_node returns 1(HAS_VALUE) if the exact key is found, 2(HAS_SUBTRIE) if the key is a sub trie, 
        # 3 if it's both 0 if it's none 
        #https://pygtrie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pygtrie.Trie.has_node

        alert_word_in_trie = trie.has_node(possible_alert_word)
        if alert_word_in_trie & pygtrie.Trie.HAS_VALUE:
            user_ids = trie.get(possible_alert_word)
            user_ids_in_messages.update(user_ids)

        deep_copy_alert_phrases = set(alert_phrases)

        # Check if extending the phrases with the current word in content is a subtrie or key. And
        # Remove the word if it is not a subtrie as we are interested only in continuos words in the content
        for alert_phrase in deep_copy_alert_phrases:
            alert_phrases.remove(alert_phrase)
            extended_alert_phrase = alert_phrase + trie._separator + possible_alert_word
            alert_phrase_in_trie = trie.has_node(extended_alert_phrase)

            if alert_phrase_in_trie & pygtrie.Trie.HAS_VALUE:
                user_ids = trie.get(extended_alert_phrase)
                user_ids_in_messages.update(user_ids)

            if alert_phrase_in_trie & pygtrie.Trie.HAS_SUBTRIE:
                alert_phrases.add(extended_alert_phrase)

        if alert_word_in_trie & pygtrie.Trie.HAS_SUBTRIE:
            alert_phrases.add(possible_alert_word)

    return user_ids_in_messages
```

**Tests**

```
input = {1 : ['hello'], 7 : ['this possible'], 2 : ['hello'], 3 : ['hello'], 5 : ['how are you'], 6 : ['hey']}
alert_word_trie = build_trie(input)
content = 'hello how is this possible how are you doing today'
result  = get_user_ids_with_alert_words(alert_word_trie, content)
assert(result == set([1, 2, 3, 5, 7]))

input = {1 : ['provisioning', 'Prod deployment'], 2 : ['test', 'Prod'], 3 : ['prod'], 4 : ['deployment'] }
alert_word_trie = build_trie(input)
content = 'Hello, everyone. Prod deployment has been completed'
result  = get_user_ids_with_alert_words(alert_word_trie, content)
assert(result == set([1, 2, 4]))

input = {1 : ['provisioning/log.txt'] }
alert_word_trie = build_trie(input)
content = 'Hello, everyone. Errors logged at provisioning/log.txt '
result  = get_user_ids_with_alert_words(alert_word_trie, content)
assert(result == set([1]))
```

The two methods are part of a larger classes which have some not so related code. You get a list of `user_id`s and their `alert_words` from the database and you process every message `content` based on the trie already build up.

This is for a chat application so frequency of running the `get_user_id_with_alert_words` is high when the `build_trie` is relatively less since it will be cached.

Comment: If `content` is `Hello, how [some words] are [more words] you`, what the result should be?

Comment: @Carcigenicate you solution iterates the entire alert_words which grows in size as users increase. Also i don't think the `in` a list is of linear time complexity.

Comment: @thebenman: `in` is O(n) for lists (and strings): https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Since the time complexity is important to you, what do you think is the time complexity of using Tries?

Comment: @Graipher Finding a word in a trie is `O(m)` where `m` is the length of the word and finding it in a list would be `O(n)` where `n` is the total number of elements in the list which can grow as opposed to the number of words in the message.

Comment: @vnp this solution expects that the exact word be found in the sentence without any trailing or preceding characters.

Answer (score 2):

This code cannot be correct.

In the function `get_user_ids_with_alert_words()` you define the empty set

```
alert_phrases = set()
```

You then make a copy of the empty set.

```
deep_copy_alert_phrases = set(alert_phrases)
```

And do a for loop over the this empty set.

```
for alert_phrase in deep_copy_alert_phrases:
```